# The spaces inside the URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created the yahoo weather API app using ASP.Net MVC 3 and when I tried to insert the postcode to the text field to find the correct xml, I wanted to leave gap for the standard UK postcode. Can you please help me to do that. The following code's `model.PostCode` represents the PostCode variable which has declared as string in model. This code is in the controller file.

```
private Boolean LookupWeather(ref RssModels model)
{    
  string WoeidUrl = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('" +
                     model.PostCode +
                     "')?appid=EzZDnOXV34EzJpQ8mX8mc62cYk1Gu21DzUhsLr.4nQ2qz.xffZah.RNq8lObxA--";

  XDocument getWoeid = XDocument.Load(WoeidUrl);

  try
  {
    model.Woied = (int)(from place in getWoeid.Descendants("place")
                        select place.Element("woeid")).FirstOrDefault();
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
```

If you can please help me to get the URL like follows.
`http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('mk10%202hn')?appid=EzZDnOXV34EzJpQ8mX8mc62cYk1Gu21DzUhsLr.4nQ2qz.xffZah.RNq8lObxA--`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

```
string WoeidUrl = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('" 
    + UrlEncode(postCode)
    + "')?appid=EzZDnOXV34EzJpQ8mX8mc62cYk1Gu21DzUhsLr.4nQ2qz.xffZah.RNq8lObxA--";
```

Comment: I gave you an example, and posted a link to the MSDN docs?  What exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

All the browser is doing for that  is replacing the space with %20, you can replicate this just by using Replace, try:

```
string postCode = model.PostCode.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

Then use it in your code above like so:

```
string WoeidUrl = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q('" 
    + postCode
    + "')?appid=EzZDnOXV34EzJpQ8mX8mc62cYk1Gu21DzUhsLr.4nQ2qz.xffZah.RNq8lObxA--";
```